# Join tables with duplicate values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, arccatalog, relates

I have two sets of data:

1. list of parcel numbers and locations which I am interested in
2. Address database for the county (shapefile)

In dataset 2 there can be multiple instances of the same parcel number with different addresses.

However in dataset 1 there is only 1 unique instance of each parcel number.

I would like to use dataset 1 to extract ALL instances of the same APN in dataset 2.

I have tried a table join but this will not work since table join looks for one and only one corresponding value for parcel number.

I need all corresponding values.

Comment: You are dealing with 1 '1-N' join, which is not supported in Join and Relates option. You might want to import your data into a .GDB and use a [relationship class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004t00000006000000.htm) to relate those two tables.

Comment: A relationship class is one way, but you may find it simpler to just use a [Relate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) in place of your Join - its available in the same place.

Comment: I think relate might work. Ill let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: Join 1 to 2. Summarise per parcel id. Joint this back to 1

Comment: If both are in the same geodatabase and you have ArcGIS version 10.1 or higher, you can Join 1 to 2 and export the features from the table of contents to get all of the parcels multiplied by the addresses joined to them.  The 1-N relationship is converted to a 1-1 relationship where all addresses will be associated with the parcel shapes and fields.  This only occurs with export/copy features etc for joined data in the same geodatabase.  The address ObjectID should be presevered so you can join the result back to the address features/table (although a custom permanent ID field is better)..

Comment: @RichardFairhurst I think your comment would suffice as an answer on this one.

Answer (score 1):

If both are in the same geodatabase and you have ArcGIS version 10.1 or higher, you can Join 1 to 2 and export the features from the table of contents to get all of the parcels multiplied by the addresses joined to them. The 1-N relationship is converted to a 1-1 relationship where all addresses will be associated with the parcel shapes and fields. This only occurs with export/copy features etc for joined data in the same geodatabase. The address ObjectID may be preserved so you can join the result back to the address features/table, although a custom permanent ID field is better to ensure that relate/join is possible.